PHP - how to draw a quadratic bezier curve using the GD library
I am using the pathCurveToQuadraticBezierAbsolute() method available in the Imagick extension to draw some random quadratic bezier curves on a colored background, like this:

I would like to try and emulate this functionality in GD but it does not include any bezier curve functions, only an arc tool and line segment tool. What calculations would I need to draw a series of arcs or line segments to emulate these quadratic bezier curves?
When using the Imagick function I have to move the cursor to a new position on the image, then I call the pathCurveToQuadraticBezierAbsolute() method with a single end point ($x and $y) and a single control point ($x1 and $y1); all coordinates are absolute. My code is currently as follows:
function draw_bezier_curve($start_x, $start_y, $points)
{
    $draw->pathStart();
    $draw->pathMoveToAbsolute($start_x, $start_y);

    foreach ($points as $key => $point) {
        $draw->pathCurveToQuadraticBezierAbsolute(
             $point['x1'],
             $point['y1'],
             $point['x'],
             $point['y']
        );
    }

    $draw->pathFinish();
}

Thank you in advance for any help or advice. I have looked at some (very old) PHP code examples but they either didn't work or the bezier curve is different to the type I want to draw, so I could not get the code to work properly.

Does this information possibly help?

@PaulT. Thank you for that. I have used this answer from that question although I will compare that with the accepted answer to see what the differences are. I've adapted the code to draw the curve using line segments instead of a filled polygon and the results are good. Here is an example image that I made with my script.

As per my last comment, I've tested the code from both answers and the output is mostly identical. dave's solution works better for thicker lines as the line segmentation looks smoother and less obvious.

Alternatively, if you want to draw shapes, don't use gd and use imagemagick instead.

I do use the Imagick extension but I'm working on an application that needs to supports both GD and Imagick, so I'm trying to emulate the bezier curve drawing in GD. I found your primer on bezier curves yesterday but haven't read it yet.
